# dt_fill raises recycle error all of a sudden

Tags: data.table

I have data wrangling script, where I just want to fill all `NA`s with the value above it. I used to do it this way:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyfast)

col1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
col2 <- c("X", NA, "Z", NA)

dt <- data.table(col1,
                 col2)

dt[, col2 := dt_fill(dt, col2, .direction = 'down')]
```

And this always worked, but now I get the error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(col2, dt_fill(dt, col2, .direction = "down"))) : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 4 items of column 'col2'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Comment: Are you using the `tidyfast` package? `dt_fill` is not in `data.table`

Comment: Yes, sorry. Didn’t check before that it’s in `tidyfast`. I have a script for wrangling large data, which all of a sudden stopped working. Might be since the new `0.4.0` release.

Comment: Going back to tidyfast 0.2.1 fixes the issue. Hopefully there will be a better solution to this soon.

Comment: ... and I see your bug report [tidyfast#54](https://github.com/TysonStanley/tidyfast/issues/54), nice.

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` has `nafill()` which doesn't work for character vectors yet but you can work around that:

```
nafill2 <- function(x) {
  if      (is.numeric(x)  ) nafill(x, type = "locf")
  else if (is.character(x)) x[nafill(replace(seq_along(x), is.na(x), NA), type = "locf")]
  else                      stop("...")
}

dt[, col2 := nafill2(col2) ]
#      col1   col2
#    <char> <char>
# 1:      A      X
# 2:      B      X
# 3:      C      Z
# 4:      D      Z
```

Comment: Nice workaround for what is (imo) a glaring omission/lack-of-capability in `nafill`